# How to check if the output of a command contains a string and then run a command if the string exists

Tags: bash, shell, loops, sh, control-flow

Example

```
if "darwin" in $MACHTYPE; 
  then
    echo "whoa it's a mac!"
fi
```

And the output should be

whoa it's a mac, if darwin is found in the output of $MACHTYPE

Please guide me!

Answer (score 2):

Provided you're using `bash`, you could use the `=~` operator:

```
if [[ "$MACHTYPE" =~ "darwin" ]]; 
then
  echo "whoa it's a mac!"
fi
```

From the `bash` man page:

> An  additional  binary  operator, =~, is available, with the same precedence as == and !=.  When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex(3)).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a version of `bash` which supports regular expressions then you can use *globbing*:

```
if [[ $MACHTYPE = *darwin* ]]  
then
    echo "whoa it's a mac!"
fi
```

Note that you must use `[[`, not `[`.

Other shells like `sh` *might* support `[[` but that is not guaranteed by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

You could evaluate your command directly, for example:

```
if uname -a | grep -i "darwin" > /dev/null; then
    echo "it is a mac"
fi
```

In this case, `grep` will exit 0 if found a value and output will be redirected to `/dev/null` if try then you can call your command, in this case: `echo "it is a mac"`

Answer (score 0):

The code below can get the output of your command on the cmd, then check if there has the specific word.

```
command="command here"

if[ `echo $command | grep -c "\"darwin\""` -gt 0 ]; then
    Do anything you want here
fi
```